# Play-Framework - Disable public folder modification reload

Tags: java, scala, extjs, playframework, development-environment

How is it possible to disable the reload of the play-framework server when saving a js (or anything else like css, json etc.) file?

Because I'm using extJS with the play-framework and the development is idle by every reload of the play-framework when I do a modification in my ext application and want to see the result in my browser.

Tanks for your contribution.

Comment: What Play version are you using? This is a known [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2905) for 2.3.1.

Comment: Yes, however I don't think it's fixed yet. Bit [tricky](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2905#issuecomment-43963267) it seems. Follow that issue to see when it get's closed.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but also in 2.3.0

Comment: If it helps someone else, I have this happen when scalariform is turned on with Play 2.4.  Disabling the plugin fixes it, though there might be a less drastic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExternalAssets

Example

GET     /ext-assets/*file controllers.ExternalAssets.at(path="/home/user/myplayapp/external", file)

Note: ExternalAssets only working in Dev mode, in Prod mode you will receive NotFound response

Answer (score -1):

use webjars for your unmodified static files like extJS, jQuery, Bootstrap or something else

Here is the list of webjars
http://www.webjars.org/documentation

And sample
http://www.webjars.org/documentation

Comment: I'm doing a ExtJS 5 application, so it's useful if you use the view system of play and need frameworks like jQuery, Bootstrap or stuff like that avalaible on http://www.jsdelivr.com/